# MongoDB group by values in an array field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have my asset documents in the below format.

```
db.asset.find({}).limit(1).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e650a10364a65f62c0df4a"),
    "_class" : "com.model.core.Asset",
    "displayName" : "Bingo Rhymes For Children + More 3D Animation Nursery Rhymes & Kids' Songs",
    "assetType" : "VIDEO",
    "active" : true,
    "originalUrl" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-tdVvvXn9k&feature=youtube_gdata",
    "groupIds" : [ ],
    "folderIds" : [
        "54e6507b0364a65f62c0df47",
        "54e6507b0364a65f62c0df48"
    ]
}
```

As you can see each asset can have a collection of folderId to which it is associated with. If I want to find the folderIds along with the associated assets how does the mongo aggregate query will look like? Essentially I want to group the assets by folderId.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. What are you trying to do? what is the expected result?

Comment: @user3100115 Essentially I want to group the assets by folderId.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first need to unwind by the `folderIds` field, than group by `_id` and push the asset `_id` into a list `assets_id`.

```
db.asset.aggregate([{$unwind:"$folderIds"},  {$group:{_id: "$folderIds",assets:{$push: {assets_id:"$_id"}}}}])
```

Comment: I think this gets me one-on-one association of the folderId vs assetId.  Here is the results of the query you suggested. db.asset.aggregate([{$unwind:"$folderIds"},  {$group:{_id:{"folderIds":"$folderIds","asset_id":"$_id"}}}])
{ "_id" : { "folderIds" : "54f8a2ed0364edbff0152df3", "asset_id" : ObjectId("55a53cfd93861c7d709af3c7") } }
{ "_id" : { "folderIds" : "54f8a2ed0364edbff0152df3", "asset_id" : ObjectId("552ff98d9386ca008fe2464c") } }.  Can I  get the assetIds grouped together for each folderId.

Comment: Thank you but the new query doesn't return any results.

Comment: Thank you. This works. db.asset.aggregate([{$unwind:"$folderIds"},  {$group:{_id: "$folderIds",assets:{$push: {assets_id:"$_id"}}}}])