# At least one common value in an array for different documents in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

What I am looking for is to find a way to display coincidence of at least one author name in different documents.

I used this setence:

```
db.papers.aggregate(
[{ $group: { _id: "$authors", docIds: { $push: "$_id" }, docCount: { $sum: 1 } } },
{ $match: { "docCount": { $gt: 1 }}}]
)
```

The result is something like this:

```
{ "_id" : [ "Valentina Sica", "Guido Kroemer" ], "docIds" : [ ObjectId("5d7d353d5deeb7978034cb0f"), ObjectId("5d7d34455deeb7978034cb08") ], "docCount" : 2 }
```

The problem is that it grouped all papers with same authors, later on I found out that they are corrections for previous papers I kept in my database (basically they are the same papers with some updates).

Update (sample document):

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d7d2ed95deeb7978034cae7"),
        "doi" : "https://doi.org/10.1038/s41422-018-0093-8",
        "orignal_link" : "https://www.nature.com/articles/s41422-018-0093-8",
        "title" : "Mitochondrial DNA synthesis fuels NLRP3 inflammasome",
        "authors" : [
                "Rebecca C. Coll",
                "Caroline L. Holley",
                "Kate Schroder"
        ],
        "affiliation" : [
                "Institute for Molecular Bioscience and IMB Centre for Inflammation and Disease Research, The University of Queensland, St Lucia, QLD, Australia"
        ],
        "citation" : [
                "Cell Research",
                [
                        " 28"
                ],
                "1046-1047",
                "2018"
        ],
        "abstract" : "N/A",
        "paper" : [
                "LPS-induced new mtDNA contributes to NLRP3 signaling. LPS binds TLR4 and induces receptor ligation, driving MyD88- and TRIF-dependent activation of transcription factors IRF1 and NF-κB. NF-κB induces the expression of NLRP3 and pro-IL-1β during inflammasome priming. IRF1 drives expression of the nucleoside monophosphate kinase CMPK2, which translocates to mitochondria and enhances the supply of dNTPs for mtDNA synthesis. NLRP3 signal 2 causes mitochondrial dysfunction and ROS production. Oxidized mtDNA directly binds NLRP3 to promote NLRP3 inflammasome assembly and signaling, leading to IL-1β secretion"
        ],
        "references" : [
                "Mangan, M. S. J. et al. Nat. Rev. Drug Discov. 17, 588–606 (2018).",
                "Zhou, R. et al. Nature 469, 221–225 (2011).",
                "Nakahira, K. et al. Nat. Immunol. 12, 222–230 (2011).",
                "Shimada, K. et al. Immunity 36, 401–414 (2012).",
                "Zhong, Z. et al. Nature 560, 198–203 (2018).",
                "Man, S. M. et al. Nat. Immunol. 16, 467–475 (2015).",
                "Bezbradica, J. S. et al. Cell Mol. Immunol. 14, 118–126 (2017).",
                "Munoz-Planillo, R. et al. Immunity 38, 1142–1153 (2013).",
                "Allam, R. et al. EMBO Rep. 15, 982–990 (2014).",
                "Heid, M. E. et al. J. Immunol. 191, 5230–5238 (2013).",
                "Yu, J. et al. Proc. Natl Acad. Sci. USA 111, 15514–15519 (2014).",
                "Schroder, K. et al. Immunobiology 217, 1325–1329 (2012)."
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Please post a sample input document.

Comment: @prasad_ I've posted an actual document from the papers collection. If I am not wrong you only need authors and ObjectId.

Comment: Please take a look at this post: [MongoDB group by values in an array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134523/mongodb-group-by-values-in-an-array-field).

Comment: _"... coincidence of at least one author name in different documents..."_: does this mean having an author's name in more than one document?

Comment: @prasad_ yes for your question "does this mean having an author's name in more than one document?".It worked using $unwind, as it was explained at the link you suggested. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Really? You posted the same link prasad_ sent me before. You pointed me as duplicating a question when you are duplicating someone's else answer.

Comment: @powerPixie : It's not like `Valijon` is posting it again, it's like he might have raised a flag to close this question as there is a similar question with a working answer, When he did raise a flag a comment will automatically be added that way :-)