# How to write group by query for embedded array of document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in below format

```js
{customerID:1,acctDetails:[{accType:"Saving",balance:100},{accType:"checking",balance:500}]}
{customerID:2,acctDetails:[{accType:"Saving",balance:500}]}
```

I want to find total balance by acctType. I tried below query.

```js
db.<collectionName>.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$acctDetails.accType",totalBalance:{$sum:"$accDetails.balace"}}}])
```

But it is not giving right result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB group by array inner-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509045/mongodb-group-by-array-inner-elements) or (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134523/mongodb-group-by-values-in-an-array-field) - you need to `$unwind` first !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this might solve your problem. You first need to use `$unwind` to transform each array element in a document, then use `$group` to sum the total balance by account type.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind": "$acctDetails"},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$acctDetails.accType",
      "totalBalance": {"$sum": "$acctDetails.balance"}
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7IyPPS-tfvJ)